# awk OR statement

Tags: awk

Does awk have an `OR` statement *i.e* given the following snippet:

```
awk '{if ($2=="abc") print "blah"}'
```

Is it possible to add an `OR` statement so that if `$2==abc OR def -> print`?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes. There's logical OR `||` that you can use:

```
awk '{if ($2=="abc" || $2=="def") print "blah" }'
```

Answer (score 51):

You would not write this code in awk:

```
awk '{if ($2=="abc") print "blah"}'
```

you would write this instead:

```
awk '$2=="abc" {print "blah"}'
```

and to add an "or" would be either of these depending on what you're ultimately trying to do:

```
awk '$2~/^(abc|def)$/ {print "blah"}'

awk '$2=="abc" || $2=="def" {print "blah"}'

awk '
BEGIN{ split("abc def",tmp); for (i in tmp) targets[tmp[i]] }
$2 in targets {print "blah"}
'
```

That last one would be most appropriate if you have several strings you want to match.

Comment: Could you explain why you wouldn't use the first version?

Comment: @ae0709 the body of an awk script is a series of `<condition> { <action> }` statements. That first script is using a null condition (true by default) and then embedding a condition inside the action part of the script inside an if statement. Idiomatically it's like if in C you wrote `if ( true ) { if (foo) { do_bar() } }` instead of just `if (foo) { do_bar() }`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{if ($2=="abc" || $2=="def") print "blah"}'
```