# Linux- awk looking for two variables in one column

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have this table:

[image]

It is a spreadsheet file I believe.

It has thousands of rows and 20 columns in total. I want to filter all these results down to specific values in certain columns.

So I wanted to find all SNPs on chromosome 1 (Second column) and all on the + strand (seventh column) and either A/T OR C/T (tenth column). Then return the number of SNPs that match these.

So far I have tried this-

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} $1=="chr1" && $7=="+" && $10=="A/T" SNP.txt | wc -l
```

I just dont know how to get column 10 to that and/or I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace image with text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839723/awk-or-statement

Comment: We can't write code to parse a picture. Post concise, testable sample input and expected output - something we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0):

your end quote is missing

```
awk -F'\t' '$1=="chr1" && $7=="+" && $10~/^(A|C)\/T$/" {count++}
            END  {print count}' SNP.txt
```

obviously not tested on the image.  Assumes the delimiter is tab as in your script.

the last condition can be changed to `($10=="A/T" || $10=="C/T")`, perhaps easier to read that way.